# how to add Upload Progress bar to files upload in Angular6

Tags: javascript, angular

I used this code to upload files in `Angular 6`.

Everything works fine but I need to add the progress bar to the code. After searching from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), I saw this code below but being new to `angular` or `angular6` I do not know how to integrate it or make the progress bar works with the `angular` form submission.

```
this.uploader.onProgressItem = (progress: any) => {    
  console.log(progress['progress']);    
};

this.uploader.onSuccessItem = (progress: any) => {
  console.log('I receive the response file posted in API');    
};
```

[Progress Bar in ng2-file-upload in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779303/progress-bar-in-ng2-file-upload-in-angular-6)

Below is the code

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FileUploader, FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

const URL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/upload';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'app';

    public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: URL, itemAlias: 'photo' });

    ngOnInit() {
        this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => { file.withCredentials = false; };
        this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {
            console.log('ImageUpload:uploaded:', item, status, response);
            alert('File uploaded successfully');
        };
    }
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<input type="file" name="photo" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s"
  (click)="uploader.uploadAll()"    
  [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length" >
  Upload an Image  
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using ng2-file-upload library, you can utilize the progress from this.uploader.queue and show it in your html.

uploader.queue is an array. if you are using it for single file upload you can access the uploading item from uploader.queue[0] and show your progress bar i.e:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': uploader.queue[0].progress + '%', 'height': '5px' }" tooltip="{{uploader.queue[0].progress}}% uploaded" placement="bottom"></div>
```

am using bootstrap 4 progress bar class in this example. Hope this helps.

Comment: I amend your code a little bit and it works for me. Here is it. 
<div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
<div class="progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
                        </div>  thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use HttpClient to upload a file, you can retrieve the progress status from the upload request. You would basically have a method that looks like this:

```
public upload(endPoint: string, payload: any): Observable<any> {
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.apiUrl + endPoint, payload, {reportProgress: true});
    return this.http.request(req);
}
```

This method returns a response containing the progress of the upload. You can then create an attribute in your component that computes the completed percent of the upload:

```
...
if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
  this.percentComplete = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
} else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
  // do something with body event.body
}
...
```